# How to create struct of bit fields in IDA?

Tags: ida

Suppose that we have bit fields struct like this:

```
struct PartInfo
{
  unsigned int day:5;
  unsigned int month:4;
  unsigned int year:7;  // year <= 99
  unsigned int lot_no:11;  // lot_no <= 2000
  unsigned int part_id:5;  // part_id <= 30
};
```

How can I represent it in IDA?

Comment: Does its [official documentation](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/500.shtml) help?

Comment: @usr2564301 What about year field and lot_no field? It does not make sense to define all these value in enum.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a struct with bitfields to the Local Types list (Shift-F1, Ins) but they are not currently supported by the decompiler or on the disassembly level.